# jQuery fullcalendar resource week views

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I use jquery fullcalendar in my projects, but I need to create a views with a resource on a week. 
I found different views for resource on a single day but neve found on for a week. Someone had just develop something like this?

Comment: I have found this project on github that have this function, https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar but if I try demo don't work

Comment: any update in this Issue?...

Comment: Yes, I have solved with http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews

Comment: @LucaRaldiri :I cannot Find this page its 404 not found

Comment: @Krishna sorry, link to github is this https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar